# Docker Issue: Removing a Bind-Mounted Volume

Tags: docker, command-line, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I have been unable to find any help online for this simple mistake I made, so I was looking for some help. I am using a server to run a docker image in a container and I mistyped and have caused an annoyance for myself. I ran the command

```
docker run --rm -v typo:location docker_name
```

and since I had a typo with the directory to mount it created a directory on the host machine, and when the container ended the directory remained. I tried to remove it, but i just get the error

```
rm -rf typo/
rm: cannot remove 'typo': Permission denied
```

I know now that I should have used `--mount` instead of `-v` for safety, but the damage is done; how can I remove this directory without having access to the container that created it?

I apologize in advance, my knowledge of docker is quite limited. I have mostly learned it only to use a particular image and I do a bunch of Google searches to do the rest.

Comment: You should be able to use `sudo` to get root permissions.  The syntax you show `docker run -v name:/container/path` creates a Docker _named volume_ that doesn't have an accessible location on the host, though; `docker volume rm typo` would delete it.

Comment: @DavidMaze So, I do not have `sudo` permissions, so that option is not viable for me. The command `docker volume rm typo` returns with the error `Error: No such volume: typo`. From here, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first rule of Docker security is, if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can get unrestricted root access over the entire host.

So you can fix this issue by running a container, running as root and bind-mounting the parent directory, that can delete the directory in question:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v "$PWD:/pwd" \
  busybox \
  rm -rf /pwd/typo
```

> I do not have `sudo` permissions

You can fix that

```sh
docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers
```

(This has implications in a lot of places.  Don't indiscriminately add users to a `docker` group, particularly on a multi-user system, since they can trivially get root access.  Be careful publishing the host's Docker socket into a container, since the container can then root the host; perhaps redesign your application to avoid needing it.  Definitely do not expose the Docker socket over the network.)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed; binding the mount and removing from the docker worked. Thank you so much!